# Errors with Fastlane + GitHub Actions for MacOS Project

Tags: xcode, macos, github-actions, fastlane

I'm trying to setup GitHub Actions with Fastlane and getting the following error: `no implicit conversion of nil into String`. Below is the full output:

```
default_platform(:mac)

DEVELOPER_APP_ID = ENV["DEVELOPER_APP_ID"]
DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER = ENV["DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER"]
PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = ENV["PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER"]
TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER = ENV["TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER"]
TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD = ENV["TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"]
APPLE_ISSUER_ID = ENV["APPLE_ISSUER_ID"]
APPLE_KEY_ID = ENV["APPLE_KEY_ID"]
APPLE_KEY_CONTENT = ENV["APPLE_KEY_CONTENT"]
GIT_AUTHORIZATION = ENV["GIT_AUTHORIZATION"]

def delete_temp_keychain(name)
  UI.message("Debug: Deleting temporary keychain #{name}...")
  delete_keychain(
    name: name
  ) if File.exist? File.expand_path("~/Library/Keychains/#{name}-db")
end

def create_temp_keychain(name, password)
  UI.message("Debug: Creating temporary keychain #{name}...")
  create_keychain(
    name: name,
    password: password,
    unlock: false,
    timeout: 0
  )
end

def ensure_temp_keychain(name, password)
  delete_temp_keychain(name)
  if password.nil? || password.empty?
    UI.error("Error: Password for temporary keychain is missing.")
  end
  create_temp_keychain(name, password)
end

platform :mac do
  lane :beta do
    UI.message("Debug: Starting the beta lane...")
    
    keychain_name = TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER
    keychain_password = TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD

    UI.message("Debug: Ensuring temporary keychain...")
    ensure_temp_keychain(keychain_name, keychain_password)

    UI.message("Debug: Validating keychain variables...")
    if keychain_password.nil? || keychain_password.empty?
      UI.error("Error: TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD is not set.")
    end

    UI.message("Debug: Creating App Store Connect API key...")
    api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(
      key_id: APPLE_KEY_ID,
      issuer_id: APPLE_ISSUER_ID,
      key_content: APPLE_KEY_CONTENT,
      duration: 1200,
      in_house: false
    )
    
    UI.message("Debug: Incrementing build number...")
    increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "Meter.xcodeproj")
    
    UI.message("Debug: Running match...")
    match(
      type: 'appstore',
      app_identifier: "#{DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER}",
      git_basic_authorization: Base64.strict_encode64(GIT_AUTHORIZATION),
      readonly: true,
      keychain_name: keychain_name,
      keychain_password: keychain_password,
      api_key: api_key
    )

    UI.message("Debug: Building the project with gym...")
    gym(
      configuration: "Release",
      project: "Meter.xcodeproj",
      scheme: "Meter",
      export_method: "app-store",
      export_options: {
        provisioningProfiles: {
          DEVELOPER_APP_ID => PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER
        }
      }
    )

    UI.message("Debug: Uploading to TestFlight with pilot...")
    pilot(
      apple_id: "#{DEVELOPER_APP_ID}",
      app_identifier: "#{DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER}",
      skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true,
      skip_submission: true,
      distribute_external: false,
      notify_external_testers: false,
      ipa: "./your_app_name.ipa"
    )

    UI.message("Debug: Deleting temporary keychain...")
    delete_temp_keychain(keychain_name)

    UI.message("Debug: Beta lane completed successfully!")
  end
end
```

This is the content of the Fastfile I am using:

```
# Fastfile
default_platform(:mac)

DEVELOPER_APP_ID = ENV["DEVELOPER_APP_ID"]
DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER = ENV["DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER"]
PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = ENV["PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER"]
TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER = ENV["TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER"]
TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD = ENV["TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"]
APPLE_ISSUER_ID = ENV["APPLE_ISSUER_ID"]
APPLE_KEY_ID = ENV["APPLE_KEY_ID"]
APPLE_KEY_CONTENT = ENV["APPLE_KEY_CONTENT"]
GIT_AUTHORIZATION = ENV["GIT_AUTHORIZATION"]

def delete_temp_keychain(name)
  UI.message("Debug: Deleting temporary keychain #{name}...")
  delete_keychain(
    name: name
  ) if File.exist? File.expand_path("~/Library/Keychains/#{name}-db")
end

def create_temp_keychain(name, password)
  UI.message("Debug: Creating temporary keychain #{name}...")
  create_keychain(
    name: name,
    password: password,
    unlock: false,
    timeout: 0
  )
end

def ensure_temp_keychain(name, password)
  delete_temp_keychain(name)
  if password.nil? || password.empty?
    UI.error("Error: Password for temporary keychain is missing.")
  end
  create_temp_keychain(name, password)
end

platform :mac do
  lane :beta do
    UI.message("Debug: Starting the beta lane...")
    
    keychain_name = TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER
    keychain_password = TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD

    UI.message("Debug: Ensuring temporary keychain...")
    ensure_temp_keychain(keychain_name, keychain_password)

    UI.message("Debug: Validating keychain variables...")
    if keychain_password.nil? || keychain_password.empty?
      UI.error("Error: TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD is not set.")
    end

    UI.message("Debug: Creating App Store Connect API key...")
    api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(
      key_id: APPLE_KEY_ID,
      issuer_id: APPLE_ISSUER_ID,
      key_content: APPLE_KEY_CONTENT,
      duration: 1200,
      in_house: false
    )
    
    UI.message("Debug: Incrementing build number...")
    increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "Meter.xcodeproj")
    
    UI.message("Debug: Running match...")
    match(
      type: 'appstore',
      app_identifier: "#{DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER}",
      git_basic_authorization: Base64.strict_encode64(GIT_AUTHORIZATION),
      readonly: true,
      keychain_name: keychain_name,
      keychain_password: keychain_password,
      api_key: api_key
    )

    UI.message("Debug: Building the project with gym...")
    gym(
      configuration: "Release",
      project: "Meter.xcodeproj",
      scheme: "Meter",
      export_method: "app-store",
      export_options: {
        provisioningProfiles: {
          DEVELOPER_APP_ID => PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER
        }
      }
    )

    UI.message("Debug: Uploading to TestFlight with pilot...")
    pilot(
      apple_id: "#{DEVELOPER_APP_ID}",
      app_identifier: "#{DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER}",
      skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true,
      skip_submission: true,
      distribute_external: false,
      notify_external_testers: false,
      ipa: "./your_app_name.ipa"
    )

    UI.message("Debug: Deleting temporary keychain...")
    delete_temp_keychain(keychain_name)

    UI.message("Debug: Beta lane completed successfully!")
  end
end
```

Not really sure exactly WHAT is causing the nil error; any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering, "no implicit conversion of nil into String," typically occurs when you're trying to perform a string operation on a variable that is nil. In your Fastlane script, there are several places where you're using environment variables that might be nil or empty. Let's go through your script and identify potential issues:

Check `TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER` and `TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD`:

Make sure that `TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER` and `TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD` environment variables are set and not nil.
Ensure that you've defined these environment variables in your GitHub Actions workflow or wherever you're triggering this Fastlane script.
Check `APPLE_KEY_ID`, `APPLE_ISSUER_ID`, and `APPLE_KEY_CONTENT`:

These environment variables should also be defined and not nil.
Verify that the values you've set for these environment variables are correct.
Check `DEVELOPER_APP_ID`, `DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER`, and `PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER`:

Ensure that these environment variables are set and not nil.
Confirm that the values are correct and match your project setup.
Verify `GIT_AUTHORIZATION`:

Make sure `GIT_AUTHORIZATION` is defined and not nil.
Ensure that it contains the necessary credentials in the correct format.
Check ipa: "./your_app_name.ipa" in the pilot step:

Ensure that you have an IPA file named "your_app_name.ipa" in the root directory of your project. If the file is located in a different directory, you need to specify the correct path.
Additionally, ensure that all your environment variables are correctly defined in your GitHub Actions secrets or environment variables settings. Double-check for typos or discrepancies in variable names.

By addressing these points and making sure that all required environment variables are set correctly, you should be able to resolve the "no implicit conversion of nil into String" error in your GitHub Actions workflow using Fastlane.

Also, when you need to validate that it is not nil or empty, you can simplify the code by using `to_s` because directly if the variable is nil when converted to string it would be empty quotes `''`.

```rb
UI.message("Debug: Validating keychain variables...")

# e.g
if keychain_password.to_s.empty?
# if keychain_password.nil? || keychain_password.empty?
  UI.error("Error: TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD is not set.")
end
```